# Get list of compiled modules within Modelsim library

Tags: modelsim

I've been scouring the [Modelsim Command Reference](https://www.microsemi.com/document-portal/doc_view/136364-modelsim-me-10-4c-command-reference-manual-for-libero-soc-v11-7) and have been unable to find this. I'm trying to find a command or a file that will give me the list of already compiled modules within a given library. I looked at [Dave's answer from @85431](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/85431/222325) and as it sounds decent, my libraries do not contain these `_primary.dat` files he refers to. When I have everything compiled, my directory looks like this:

```
work
| _info
| _lib.qdb
| _lib1_1.qdb
| _lib1_1.qpg
| _lib1_1.qtl
| _vmake
```

From what I can make of these files (which isn't much), my target would probably be the `_info` file as I could probably do a Regex search of the file to find the module names from it.

However I guess I'm just hoping that there might be a command that will list these for me in some way? I feel like the Regex method might give be some false-positives in the search in that it will say a module is in there when it was actually a dependency of a higher-level module in the hierarchy. I can't say this for certain as I'm not 100% certain I'm reading the file correctly.

If there's a command out there and someone can find/knows about it, or if I'm just missing something here! I would greatly appreciate any clarification.

Edit: Also, to be clear, I'm trying to do this just by examining the library without actually loading a simulation/design.

Answer (score 1):

I found it! I feel dumb too, but here she is in all her glory:

## vdir

This command lists the contents of a design library and checks the compatibility of a vendor library. If vdir cannot read a vendor-supplied library, the library may not be compatible with ModelSim.

This command provides additional information with the -help switch.

#### Syntax

```
vdir [-l | [-prop <prop>]] [-r] [-all | [-lib <library_name>]] [<design_unit>]
[-modelsimini <path/modelsim.ini>]
```